# Long time to exec a simple query in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, configuration

I am with a performance problem in my MySQL database, and do not know if it's the server configuration issue or disk space, or simply not riding the query correctly.

a simple query that summarizes the total number of rows in a table by a distinct field, it takes more than 3 minutes. The status is "Sending data" for a long time.

the query is as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT (ca.nm_slug)) the qtd_total
FROM consulta_atual ca
WHERE ca.cd_categoria_site = 436
```

below the description of the table (has a 4 million records)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consulta_atual` (
  `cd_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cd_categoria_site` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ds_categoria` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ds_subcategoria` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cd_produto_price` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `cd_seq` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tp_fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `nm_slug` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fornecedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_img_fornecedor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `url_raiz_fornecedor` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `url_imagem` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `url_produto` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `vlr_produto` varchar(49) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pnt_produto` varchar(53) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vlr_produto_original` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `menor_valor` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `maior_valor` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtd_lojas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cd_produto_price`,`fornecedor`),
  KEY `nm_slug_2` (`nm_slug`),
  KEY `ds_categoria` (`ds_categoria`),
  KEY `vlr_produto_original` (`vlr_produto_original`),
  KEY `cd_categoria_site` (`cd_categoria_site`),
  KEY `fornecedor` (`fornecedor`),
  KEY `tp_fornecedor` (`tp_fornecedor`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ds_categoria_2` (`ds_categoria`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ds_categoria_3` (`ds_categoria`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can I improve execution performance of this simple query?

Comment: Create a composite index over `(cd_categoria_site, nm_slug)`.

Comment: I have these two columns separate index . It makes more difference to create an index together? remove the separate index ?

Comment: Yes. MySQL will just use 1 index on a table in a query. So with 2 indexes you just give it the choice of finding the specified value of cd_categoria_site or counting the distinct values of nm_slug (which it can't do without checking cd_categoria_site first). Also worth possibly running ANALYZE TABLE if it hasn't been done for a while

Comment: I understand, then I have to create an index for each query using different fields from the table ? I am creating the suggested index , so complete report the result of the query

Comment: Sometimes an index specific to a query is needed.